# Ant regex expression

Tags: regex, ant

Quite a simple one in theory but can't quite get it!

I want a regex in ant which matches anything as long as it has a slash on the end.

Below is what I expect to work

```
<regexp id="slash.end.pattern" pattern="*/"/>
```

However this throws back

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*/
^
```

I have also tried escaping this to `\*`, but that matches a literal `*`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `*/` if you want to match `/`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be as simple as [`/$`](http://regex101.com/r/sJ3uT8) (note: I've never used ant)?

Comment: Got it (.)*/$ did the job fine

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try `/$` as Sam suggested?  The regex does exactly what you asked for, but it doesn't *consume* anything but the final `/`.  I'm wondering if that's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original regex pattern didn't work because `*` is a special character in regex that is only used to quantify other characters.

The pattern `(.)*/$`, which you mentioned in your comment, will match any string of characters not containing newlines, however it uses a possibly unnecessary capturing group. `.*/$` should work just as well.

If you need to match newline characters, the dot `.` won't be enough.  You could try something like `[\s\S]*/$`

On that note, it should be mentioned that you might not want to use `$` in this pattern.  Suppose you have the following string:

`abc/def/`

Should this be evaluated as two matches, `abc/` and `def/`?  Or is it a single match containing the whole thing?  Your current approach creates a single match.  If instead you would like to search for strings of characters and then stop the match as soon as a `/` is found, you could use something like this: `[\s\S]*?/`.

Comment: "[A]nything as long as it has a slash on the end" seems pretty clear to me, but if I wanted to match every substring that ends with a slash, I'd use `[^/]+/` (or `[^/]*/` if a match of `/` alone is acceptable).

Comment: True, that's actually a more straightforward solution.